Usage inhabituel de la conjonction de coordination « car » (Molloy, Samuel Beckett)
Passage tiré de Molloy, Samuel Beckett

Il regardait autour de lui, je l’ai déjà fait remarquer, comme pour graver dans sa
mémoire les caractéristiques du chemin, et il dut voir le rocher à l’ombre duquel j’étais tapi, à la façon de Belacqua, ou de Sordello, je ne me rappelle plus. Mais un homme, à plus forte raison moi, ça ne fait pas exactement partie des caractéristiques d’un chemin, car.

« Car » doit être la  conjonction de coordination dans ce texte, pas le nom qui signifie « véhicule ».
Comment expliquer le placement  cette conjonction en fin de phrase ? Le français de Beckett, qui était d'origine irlandaise, serait-il en cause ?

Il faut espérer que le temps viendra où la meilleure manière d'utiliser le langage sera de le malmener de la façon la plus efficace possible

@Frank Et Beckett est un auteur qui a très bien réussi à faire ça. J'ai vraiment hésité à répondre, ce n'est pas du tout, mais absolument pas une question de français. On est dans le commentaire littéraire, et la question devrait être posée sur Literature, non ?

@Kamala-1FTW La raison de cela est que cette phrase contient un autre problème que je ne veux pas voir mêlé à celui de la conjonction.

@LPH Et pourtant c'est bien le même « problème ».  Isoler une phrase de son contexte en empêche la compréhension. Dans le cas présent on ne peut rien comprendre si on ne se rend pas compte que c'est une question de style et non de grammaire.

Non, le français de Beckett n'est pas en cause, seulement le rendu littéraire du style direct. Car introduit manifestement un raisonnement à l'appui de l'assertion qui précède ("un homme ne fait pas partie des caractéristiques d'un chemin") au moment même où locuteur perçoit qu'expliciter ce raisonnement serait enfoncer une porte ouverte.

@None C'est une citation de Beckett lui-même. Je me suis dit que ça "répondait" à la question de façon concise...

@Frank Je ne la connaissais pas - (ou je l'avais oubliée) donc pas reconnue.  Oui, la lettre à Axel Kaun, bonne citation.

@Kamala-1FTW Un principe fondamental de la grammaire est que c'est un système dont la portée se limite à la phrase.  La grammaire est peut-être en retard sur les écrivains avancés ou autres utilisateurs de la langue, mais elle n'évolue pas dans le sens de considérer une syntaxe à plusieurs phrases, et d'apprendre à l'utilisateur courant autre chose  (anglais et français, pour le moins).

@Kamala-1FTW C'est carrément impossible d'avoir une telle attitude ; c'est tellement courant… Il y a plus, comme le grand nombre de phrases qui commencent par « mais » : il faut aller chercher ce à quoi la réserve est faite non seulement dans la phrase précédente mais parfois dans plusieurs des phrases qui précèdent.

La langue ne réside pas uniquement dans la grammaire et la sémantique. De surcroit, quand on lit de la littérature, il faut tenir compte du style et de ce que veut communiquer l'auteur. Dans Molloy (le premier roman de Beckett qui, précisons le, maitrisait parfaitement le français) la langue est au service de la pensée du personnage dont on va suivre la dégradation. On ne lit pas une description, on lit la pensée de Molloy. Le personnage est défaillant, sa pensée est défaillante, il se reprend  constamment, il hésite, (ne ne sais plus, je ne me rappelle plus, je ne me rappelle pas, je m'exprime mal, je ne suis pas sûr, etc.).
On peut de la même façon mettre en parallèle de ta citation ce passage qui se situe quelques lignes plus loin : « Et pourtant. Or ce monsieur serait-il venu de loin, nu-tête, en espadrilles... ». Pourquoi ce « Or » en début de phrase, on cherche à faire le lien avec ce qui suit et ce qui précède dans la pensée de Molloy.
Ou cet autre passage, aussi quelques lignes plus loin : « Alors voilà, je suis fixé sur certaines choses, je sais certaines choses sur lui, des choses que j’ignorais, qui me tracassaient, des choses même dont je n’avais pas souffert. Quelle langue. Je suis même capable d’avoir appris quel est son métier,... ». Que fait ce « quelle langue » entre deux points ? À quoi le relier dans la pensée de Molloy ? De quelle langue s'agit-il ? S'agit-il de ce qu'« on [lui] dit », ou de ce qu'il a du mal à exprimer¹ ?
La ponctuation joue-t-elle un rôle ? Le point représente-t-il une rupture grammaticale ou une pause dans la pensée du personnage qui réfléchit, qui se reprend ? Ce « car » finit-il vraiment une phrase ou introduit-il une phrase ? Phrase qui serait aussi bancale à qui se placerait dans un optique de grammaire traditionnelle ou chaque mot doit avoir un rôle prédéfini.

Mais un homme, à plus forte raison moi, ça ne fait pas exactement partie des caractéristiques d’un chemin, car. Je veux dire que si par extraordinaire il doit un jour repasser par là, après un long laps de temps, vaincu, ou pour chercher une chose oubliée, ou pour brûler quelque chose, c’est le rocher qu’il cherchera des yeux, et non pas le hasard à son ombre de cette chose bougeante et fugitive qu’est la chair encore vivante.

Rappelons-nous que Beckett est une des figures phares du Théâtre de l'absurde, et la déstructuration de la pensée au cœur de ce théâtre est aussi présente dans ses romans.
En littérature on appelle stream of consciousness³ cette façon d'écrire où l'auteur transcrit sous forme de monologue intérieur les pensées de son personnage telles qu'elles lui viennent à l'esprit.
Note
Beckett a écrit Molloy en français d'abord (publié en 1951) et en a fait la traduction en anglais lui-même (publié en 1955). Voici la façon dont l'auteur a rédigé en anglais le passage cité dans la question :

But a man, a fortiori myself, isn’t exactly a landmark, because, I mean if by some strange chance he were to pass that way again, after a long lapse of time, vanquished, or to look for...

Nous constatons donc que Beckett a remplacé par une virgule le point mis en français. Dans les deux cas c'est la rupture dans la pensée du personnage qui est reflétée. Tout au juste pourrait-on se demander si le temps que met Molloy à retrouver le fil de son raisonnement est plus long dans le point ou dans la virgule²...

¹ Toutes les questions que je pose sont, bien sûr rhétoriques. Elles n'attendent pas d'autre réponse que celle que chacun peut se faire pour lui-même. 
² Et au cas où certains voient là encore une question, elle est pour moi tout aussi rhétorique et je ne cherche pas de réponse, ça ne change en rien la lecture que je fais du roman. 
³ Parfois traduit par « flux de conscience », mais le terme anglais est souvent employé, cette technique d'écriture est née dans la littérature anglophone même si des auteurs français l'ont aussi employée.

Je suis d'accord avec l'analyse littéraire.

La conclusion à laquelle on est forcé est que ce n'est pas grammatical, que c'est de la langue inventée et que l'on ne peut pas prendre comme modèle dans nos propres écrits au risque de passer pour un ignorant. // Je ne vois en ce « car » qu'une très mauvaise connexion logique avec la phrase qui suit.

@LPH Le fil des pensées est-il toujours logique ? Il ne l'est pas chez moi en tous cas. Et je sais que je ne suis pas la seule à avoir des pensées qui passent du coq à l'âne, qui se bousculent, se chevauchent, s’interrompent, se chassent... et refléter ceci est le propre du  stream of consciousness. Une langue inventée ? Je ne peux pas dire ça puisque c'est la langue que je me parle, que Molloy se parle, que nous nous parlons... Une langue inventée ce serait une langue qui n'existe pas (par exemple le Dothraki, qui est une langue de fiction)....

..  Bien entendu quand on veut rédiger, une lettre officielle, un devoir scolaire, un article de revue universitaire il ne vaut mieux pas écrire ainsi mais nous sommes en présence d’œuvres d'art,  tout autre domaine.  Quand on voit le nombre d'auteurs qui ont écrit des romans à succès en utilisant cette technique, certains ayant le Prix Nobel de littérature  (outre Beckett: Faulkner, Camus, Claude Simon, Sartre...) on ne peut pas dire qu'écrire ainsi reflète une quelconque ignorance.

Joyce ne l'a jamais eu le Prix Nobel de littérature, ce pour quoi en son temps l'Académie Suédoise avait reçu des critiques, d'aucuns évoquant des raisons politiques.

Je ne reconnais pas dans son style le véritable « stream of consciousness » : il existe dans son récit presque toujours un haut degrés de connections des idées.

Véritable  « stream of consciousness » ? Tu as ta propre définition ? Suite va suivre ...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
